# SMOTE Reduced No. of Observations

Tags: r, logistic-regression, smote

I am trying logisitic regression on a loan default dataset and wonder why SMOTE has reduced the number of observations. The original dataset had .226786 observations and when i ran smote, the total # of observations reduced to 53440 . Is this normal ?

```
train$loan_status<-as.factor(train$loan_status)
train_smote <-SMOTE(loan_status~.,train,perc.over = 100,k = 5, perc.under = 200)
```

0     1 
26720 26720

Thank you

Comment: To understand the expectations of the SMOTE implementation you're using, you should mention which package it's from (and check it's documentation too, if you haven't).

Comment: Assuming you're using the version from [DMwR, the documentation details](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/SMOTE) explain how the `perc.over` and `perc.under` parameters work. You set `perc.over = 100` which means you will keep the same number of minority class observations, though with `perc.under = 200` I would expect 2 majority cases for each minority case, but your table seems to show 1:1...

Comment: @GregorThomas - Thank you so much . I understand this better now. Yes, I am using SMOTE from the DMwR package. Would you please help me understand how to decide what perc.over and under number must be ? There has to be a way to find the optimum

Comment: I've never used SMOTE before. Cross validation would probably be the best way to find the optimum. The point of SMOTE is oversampling the minority class. When you set `perc.over = 100` you are not oversampling, so I would think you're not really using SMOTE at all, you're just undersampling the majority class. The default `perc.over` is 200, generally I would not adjust the default without a reason (such as trying an adjustment with cross validation and seeing that it does better than the default).